# Does Jmeter's webdriver sampler clear firefox cookie and cache before start?

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

When Jmeter start an istance of firefox, it seem to be using a custom profile. Does it clear the cache and cookie before start? Dose it re-use cookie and cache if it keep looping the same page over and over?

Answer (score 2):

1. When Firefox instance is started by JMeter's WebDriver sampler it is "clean"
2. It does re-use cookies and cache on each iteration unless you tick "Create a new Browser at the start of each iteration" box under "Experimental" tab

   [image: Firefox Driver Config]
3. If you have more than one consecutive WebDriver Sampler request like:

   - Thread Group

     - WebDriver Sampler 1
     - WebDriver Sampler 2

   The same Firefox instance will be used in both samplers, so if you stop somewhere at the end of the "Sampler 1" browser will continue from where you left off in the "Sampler 2".

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) for more JMeter WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks.